# Responsive design for different resolutions in the same stylesheet

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a little patch for one of my favorite video sites using the Stylish Chrome extension and a bit of media query magic:

```
@media screen (min-width: 1920px, max-width: 2559px) {
    div#player div#player-api {
        width: 1280px;
        height: 720px;
    }
}

@media screen (min-width: 2560px) {
    div#player div#player-api {
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that I'm always matching *both* conditions, as if the media queries aren't being required at all. Is the above valid CSS? Do I have the right idea for dynamically scaling an element with CSS based on browser size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only missing some small things.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px)and (max-width: 2559px) {
    div#player div#player-api {
        width: 1280px;
        height: 720px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
    div#player div#player-api {
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }
}
```

I suggest you a [good blog](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) on [Mediaqueries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)  for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2559px)`